# Numbering the rows per group after an orderby in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say you have columns AppleType, CreationDate and want to order each group of AppleType by CreationDate. Furthermore, you want to create a new column which explicitly ranks the order of the CreationDate per AppleType.

So, the resulting DataSet would have three columns, AppleType, CreationDate, OrderIntroduced.

Is there a LINQ way of doing this? Would I have to actually go through the data programmatically (but not via LINQ), create an array, convert that to a column and add to the DataSet? I have there is a LINQ way of doing this. Please use LINQ non-method syntax if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So are the values actually appearing in the right order? If so, it's easy - but you *do* need to use method syntax, as the query expression syntax doesn't support the relevant overload:

```
var queryWithIndex = queryWithoutIndex.Select((x, index) => new
                                              {
                                                  x.AppleType,
                                                  x.CreationDate,
                                                  OrderIntroduced = index + 1,
                                              });
```

(That's assuming you want `OrderIntroduced` starting at 1.)

I don't know offhand how you'd then put that back into a `DataSet` - but do you really *need* it in a `DataSet` as opposed to in the strongly-typed sequence?

EDIT: Okay, the requirements are still unclear, but I *think* you want something like:

```
var query = dataSource.GroupBy(x => x.AppleType)
     .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate)
                       .Select((x, index ) => new {
                               x.AppleType,
                               x.CreationDate,
                               OrderIntroduced = index + 1 }));
```

Note: The `GroupBy` and `SelectMany` calls here *can* be put in query expression syntax, but I believe it would make it more messy in this case. It's worth being comfortable with both forms.

Comment: Looks good, but I don't want to simply index each row, I want to index each row with respect to ApplyType plus CreationDate. ie, each new AppleType will begin at index 1

Comment: @Ben: So add the after you group by the `AppleType` but before you flatten. It's very hard to guess exactly what you want when you haven't provided any sample queries, but I'll give it a go...

Comment: Works. Thanks! What about using Aggregate in query syntax?

Comment: @Ben: No, that has no query expression form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure Linq to Entities/SQL solution you can do something like this:

Modified to handle duplicate CreationDate's

```
var query = from a in context.AppleGroup
            orderby a.CreationDate
            select new
            {
              AppleType = a.AppleType,
              CreationDate = a.CreationDate,
              OrderIntroduced = (from b in context.AppleGroup
                                 where b.CreationDate < a.CreationDate
                                 select b).Count() + 1
            };
```

Comment: Count isn't an index, though. Would this really do what I need it to do?

Comment: @Ben B - I have updated the answer to handle duplicate CreationDates. It works since it is counting all the records that appear before it, which is essentially an index